# SolR Query using object oriented notation

Tags: php, search, lucene, solr, php-extension

I have a SolR query like this:

```
&q=*:*&fq={!geofilt pt=45.15,-93.85 sfield=store d=5}
```

How can I write the same using [SolrQuery()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.solrquery.php) object oriented notation from PHP [SolR extension API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may always use `setParam()`:

```
$query = new SolrQuery();
$query->setParam('fq', '{!geofilt pt=45.15,-93.85 sfield=store d=5}');
```

Answer (score 0):

..an example would be useful: how you use SolrQuery(), what have you tried before and are there any error messages?!

In general, you can handle the geofilt function as any other filterquery.
Simply add that to your "options"-array

```
$solrOptions=array('fq'=>'{!geofilt pt=45.15,-93.85 sfield=store d=5}');
```